# jquery up/down slider conflict with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using drupal 7 with views and I am using a jquery script for up/down text slide which I found. It worked but when I tried to use it with views exposed filters with ajax it doesn't seem to work.

I found on the net that jquery script has to use live or bind or delegate but I cant figure it out.
Below is the script I use:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.feature_box').showFeatureText();
});

jQuery.fn.showFeatureText = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var box = jQuery(this);
        var text = jQuery('p', this);
        text.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '0%'
        }).hide();
        box.hover(function() {
            text.slideDown("fast");
        }, function() {
            text.slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Be sure that when asking a question that you actually ask a question. Your post is pretty good, but you should always have an actual question. For instance, you could have stated a question like this - "How can I change the following script to work with views exposed filters?"

Answer (score 0):

convert `box.hover` into `.live` function, and if possible then use live function directly with class / id name,

```
jQuery(".class").hover(/* hover js code */);
```

OR

```
box.live("mouseover", function(){
    // mouseover js code
});

box.live("mouseout", function(){
    // mouseout js code
});
```

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I also saw that my code had a small error since i was trying to find a way to make it work on my own. Now the code the one i use and works but after the ajax load it doesnt. The suggestions maybe are helping but i am noob in programming so if you can be more precise i would appriciate it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend attaching your plugin to an element that will not be replaced via ajax. And, using on() which allows you to specify a target within your attached event handler.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.element_containing_feature_box').showFeatureText();
});

jQuery.fn.showFeatureText = function() {

    return this.on('mouseenter', '.feature_box', function(e){
        $(this).find('p').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '0%'
        }).hide();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.feature_box', function(e){
        $(this).find('p').slideUp("fast");
    });
}​
```

Or, re-calling your plugin on ajax success.

```
jQuery.ajax(options).done(function() {
    jQuery('.feature_box').showFeatureText();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but both the solutions you gave couldnt make them work . Thanks anyway